# Can't SSH to EC2 instance after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ssh, login, password, amazon-ec2

Summary:
I have Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS server running as an AWS EC2 instance. Using do-release-upgrade, 14.04.3 is installed without any problems. But after that I can't SSH into my instance. Both my private key file and password are not accepted.

Details:
Upgrade process worked smoothly. At the very last prompt, when it asks to reboot the server to complete the upgrade, I answer yes and of course my SSH session drops out. When the system restarts (as I can see in EC2 console), SSH doesn't work any more.

```
ssh -v -i <filename>.pem ubuntu@<hostname>
gives response:
....
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: <masked>
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Above is for password-less login. I have also enabled password authentication and my password is rejected.

I have a snapshot of the pre-upgrade image, so I've restored the image and retried the upgrade several times using different options - same result.

I have Webmin installed and that works fine after the upgrade, so I can access the file system without SSH to fix things if necessary.

It's such a repeatable problem for a common task that surely many others would have come across it, but searching couldn't find any hits.

Comment: Try to remove server from `known_host` with commnad `sudo ssh-keygen -R ip_of_server`, on your pc and try again to ssh to server.

Comment: Thanks @2707974. Yes I've tried removing the host key from the known_hosts file but that doesn't help. Anyway it turns out that's not necessary anyway because the host key remains the same after the upgrade. OS X warns if it detects host key mismatch.

Comment: To debug this kind of a problem on EC2, you have to take the broken instance offline and analyze its logs on a working instance. Cf. http://askubuntu.com/a/700518/383994

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened?  I think the same thing just happened to me.