# Putty not letting me to login to ubuntu remote server?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, amazon-ec2, ufw

I am using amazon ec2 instance for one of my products and i am stuck with a very big problem. I am new to server and was just looking to configure UFW for only my ipaddress and i updated a rule for it and enabled the UFW, after sometime i cleared the UFW rule and logged out of my server. But now I am not able to get into the server.. it is giving an error like..

```
Network connection timed out
```

I tried pinging to my domain address and it says

```
Pinging domain.com [52.74.68.192] with 32 bytes of data
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out. 
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 52.74.68.192:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

the ip address and the domain name provided is just example..

and even my website is giving an error like..

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

i checked my ec2 instance in the aws console..it is running. So can someone help me how i can get everything back to normal. I make use of windows system with putty for ssh connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the solution would be to log in via console, but EC2 does not support that. Their typical solution is to stop the broken instance, detach its root disk, attach it to another instance, fix the problem, and then reattach it. The tutorial is here: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598